# Why does lsp-haskell format some projects and not others?

Tags: formatting, lsp, haskell-mode

This is the message I get when I use lsp to format the current project:

```
lsp-request: No plugin enabled for STextDocumentFormatting, available: []
```

And then on another project:

```
LSP :: Applying 22 edits to `Telemetry.hs' ...
Applying 22 edits to `Telemetry.hs' ...done
```

This is puzzling. Where do I start to look for what is wrong?

Comment: It seems to be this bug: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/168064.